# Magento 1.7 - Allowed memory size exhausted - SimpleXML

Tags: xml, magento, memory

I have an error on an 1.7 Magento installation. When i try to manage products, the error: 
 `Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in [...]/src/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 667`
occurs. The only thing i did was to update the FactFinder extension. I also reverted all code changed since the error occures, but no changes.
On a second installation i have exactly the same code, but no error occures in backend.

Most confusing fact: Config.php only has 604 lines ... so i have no idea where to debug this error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same sort of problem when trying to import/export products and customers when migrating an installation of Magento. This error, I found, was server-side. You will need to contact your hosting provider and ask them to increase the memory limit in php.ini.

```
max_execution_time = 120     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 240    ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 1024M
```

Above are the values I needed to change to solve the memory size exhaustion error.

Hope this helps.